# symbolic link to desktop in windows

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I'm looking to make a symbolic link to my Desktop in windows.
The reason I want this is that I've been doing a lot of web development on my local machine
and I'm looking for a shortcut that I can type into the address bar of my browser
that will take me directly to the working directory of my web project (which is on my Desktop).

I know that I can create symbolic links using the "mklink" command in the command prompt,
but this is not accomplishing my goal, because these are not interpreted as paths in my web-browser. 
does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a symbolic link (which is a file system shortcut mechanism), consider using a bookmark (which is a browser shortcut mechanism) in your browser of choice.  If you navigate to the desktop folder in explorer, then open the main page in your browser, you can then bookmark it.

Firefox will also let you use keyword in the bookmark properties so you could use a single letter to open the dev site.  IE will let you apply a shortcut key to the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

What about just adding your Desktop to your Favorites list in Windows Exporer?  Go to Explorer, navigate to your desktop, then right click on the favorites star at the top left and select "Add current location to Favorites."  Then you'd have access to your files quickly by doing a Windows-E.

If you do need it to be a browser based shortcut, simply bookmark your desktop in your browser.